# Geometric Entropy & the Partition Function for Conical Deficits

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, entropy, geometry, partition-function

In their [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9401072), Callan and Wilczek claim to derive from the thermal entropy

$$S_\text{thermal} = -\left(\beta\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}-1\right)\ln(\mathcal{Z})$$

a **geometric** entropy which is associated with a conical deficit $\delta = {2\pi} (1-(\beta/\beta_H))$ given by

$$S_\text{BH}=\left(2\pi\frac{\partial}{\partial\delta}+1\right)\ln(\mathcal{Z})|_{\delta=0}.$$

However, when attempting to reproduce the calculation, I run into a conceptual issue with the partition function. Using $\beta= \beta_H(1-(\delta/2\pi))$, I find

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta} = -\frac{2\pi}{\beta_H}\frac{\partial}{\partial\delta}\implies \beta\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta} = -2\pi\left(1-\frac{\delta}{2\pi}\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial\delta}$$

which gives the following expression for $S_\text{thermal}$

$$S_\text{thermal}=\left(2\pi \frac{\partial}{\partial\delta}-\delta\frac{\partial}{\partial\delta}+1\right)\ln(\mathcal{Z}).$$

In order to recover $S_\text{BH}$, one has to assume that $$\left.\left(\delta\frac{\partial\ln(\mathcal{Z})}{\partial\delta}\right)\right|_{\delta=0}=0\implies \ln(\mathcal{Z}) = \sum_{k=0}c_k\delta^{k}.$$

Is there a physical reason, why one cannot include terms such as $\ln(\delta)$ or $\delta^{-k}$ in the state sum? I understand wanting to recover a finite entropy when the conical deficit disappears (in the $\delta\to0$ limit) but this limit does not **have** to be taken.